# Datatables - how to remove blank selector in dropdown column filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, datatables, dropdown

I am using DataTables with the Individual column searching (select inputs) function, but I am having an issue with the column dropdown filter.

If I enter two or more values in a cell, the filter will show a blank selector in the dropdown in between my two values (see screenshot: [column searching filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RprQr.png)).

I am pretty sure it has to do with this part of the code, but I am fairly new to Javascript, and cannot figure out how to remove that blank space:

```
column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
  if (d.indexOf("<p>") >= 0) {
    var b = d;
    $(b).each(function(index) {
      var text = $(this).text();
      select.append('<option value="' + text.trim() + '">'+ text.trim() +'</option>')
    });
  }
});
```

I have created a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/marieme/xtbzLaj9/9/ - The issue is with the "Office: All" dropdown menu.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: if(text.trim().length > 0) {//append your option value}. try this?

Comment: Brilliant! This is working.
Thank you so much @VPC.